# Converting from wide to long data: reshape function placed the values in wrong column headers

Tags: r, format, reshape, long-integer

I've spent so many hours trying to figure out how to convert my wide to long data correctly so that each item occupies two rows, one for pre-assessment and one for post-assessment. It seems so bizarre to me that when I only had up to 9 items to convert from wide to long data structure, everything looked correct.  But the moment I entered the 10th variable (I actually have 25 items, but to keep things simple, here's just 10), reshape function seemed to not guess correctly which values should go into which column headers.  The following is my data and my attempt so far:

```
>  wide <- data.frame(bk_item_1_key_pre=0.62804878,
               bk_item_2_key_pre=0.853658536585366,
               bk_item_3_key_pre=0.603658536585366,
               bk_item_4_key_pre=0.420731707317073,
               bk_item_5_key_pre=0.713414634146341,
               bk_item_6_key_pre=0.567073170731707,
               bk_item_7_key_pre=0.5,
               bk_item_8_key_pre=0.426829268292683,
               bk_item_9_key_pre=0.652439024390244,
               bk_item_10_key_pre=0.73780487804878,
               bk_item_1_key_post=0.794117647058824,
               bk_item_2_key_post=0.864705882352941,
               bk_item_3_key_post=0.594117647058824,
               bk_item_4_key_post=0.452941176470588,
               bk_item_5_key_post=0.752941176470588,
               bk_item_6_key_post=0.658823529411765,
               bk_item_7_key_post=0.5,
               bk_item_8_key_post=0.4,
               bk_item_9_key_post=0.611764705882353,
               bk_item_10_key_post=0.752941176470588)
long <- reshape(wide,
           varying=c("bk_item_1_key_pre",
                                            "bk_item_2_key_pre",
                                            "bk_item_3_key_pre",
                                            "bk_item_4_key_pre",
                                            "bk_item_5_key_pre",
                                            "bk_item_6_key_pre",
                                            "bk_item_7_key_pre",
                                            "bk_item_8_key_pre",
                                           "bk_item_9_key_pre",
                                           "bk_item_10_key_pre",
                                            "bk_item_1_key_post",
                                            "bk_item_2_key_post",
                                            "bk_item_3_key_post",
                                            "bk_item_4_key_post",
                                            "bk_item_5_key_post",
                                            "bk_item_6_key_post",
                                            "bk_item_7_key_post",
                                            "bk_item_8_key_post",
                                          "bk_item_9_key_post",
                                           "bk_item_10_key_post"),
                                  v.names=c("bk_item_1_key", 
                                            "bk_item_2_key",
                                            "bk_item_3_key",
                                            "bk_item_4_key",
                                            "bk_item_5_key", 
                                            "bk_item_6_key",
                                            "bk_item_7_key",
                                            "bk_item_8_key",
                                            "bk_item_9_key",
                                            "bk_item_10_key"),
                                  times=c("pre", "post"),
                                      new.row.names=1:1000,
                                  direction="long")
```

As you can see, item "bk_item_2_key" now contains values of "bk_item_5_key", and what should have been in "bk_item_2_key" is now in "bk_item_3_key", etc.  I'm so confused as to how this happened and do not know how to fix this problem.  I would so greatly appreciate your insights into what went wrong here.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: consider `reshape(wide, matrix(names(wide), ncol= 2),  dir='long', times = c("pre", "post"))`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
reshape(wide, matrix(names(wide), ncol= 2),  dir='long', 
        times = c("pre", "post"),  new.row.names = 1:2)

  time bk_item_1_key_pre bk_item_2_key_pre bk_item_3_key_pre bk_item_4_key_pre
1  pre         0.6280488         0.8536585         0.6036585         0.4207317   ...
2 post         0.7941176         0.8647059         0.5941176         0.4529412   ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Your code is such a game changer... it transformed the data correctly with so little text compared to mine :). Btw, do you happen to know why my code yielded erroneous results?  So for example, for bk_item_2_key, it would give me 0.7378049 and 0.7529412, for pre and post, respectively, when these values should belong to bk_item_10_key.  Thank you for any additional insights any one can provide!

Comment: @Anita might be the wrong ordering of characters. I do not know why.

Comment: yeah, it must be.  Thank you for your code though @ Onyambu.  I will use it whenever I need to convert from wide to long, to be safe :)!